# Why is my Image.Source still black after setting it's stream?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap

So I am trying to add a "screenshot" onto the source of the Image by saving the Bitmap to the stream and the setting the Source to the BitmapImage.

But for some reason the Image control is just black it doesnt show anything. 
Why is that?

```
//this.Hide();
//Create a black bitmap with the correct width and height and use it as a "Canvas" that we will
//be performing a bit-block transfer on. (Bitmap is mutable)
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);


//To perform a bit-block transfer we need the object to be a "Graphics" object.
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen);


//Perform the bit-block transfer and alter the image.
//Source being the screens pixels, and the destination is the black bitmap.
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);


//Create a temporary memory stream for the image.
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Save the graphics object (image) in the memory stream. with a specified format.
    printscreen.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    var ImageSource = new BitmapImage();
    ImageSource.BeginInit();
    ImageSource.StreamSource = mStream;
    ImageSource.EndInit();
    ImageBox.Source = ImageSource;
}
```

As you can see I am setting the Source property to the ImageSource yet it's black.

WPF

```
<Window x:Class="eh.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:eh"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="Black" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Left="0" Top="0" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="ImageBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="1920" Width="1080"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Do you have to reset the memorystream position to 0 after assigning data?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the CacheOption so I added

```
ImageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
```